# Java : Getting unchecked cast required warning

Tags: java

I am trying to write a generic class definition for class `UniCourse` that stores students that are registered in the course.

It creates `UniCourse` objects that use student emails as identities (e.g. abc123 :: (Type `String`), or student Id :: (Type `Integer`).

I'm getting this warning:

> unchecked cast required: T[] found: java.lang.Object[]

Could someone explain what this means and how to fix this?

```
public class UniCourse<T> {
    private T[] students;

    public UniCourse (int size) {
    T[] students = (T[]) new Object[size];
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you create a `Student` class and create a `Student[]` array instead?

Comment: @QBrute explained above is like a prompt. I need to create a generic class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a generic array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

One Solution would be to create your own Student Class which holds an array of your data as an Object.
Your Student Class could look like this:

```
public class Student<T> {
    protected Object[] data;

    public Student (int size) {
    this.data = new Object[size];
  }
}
```

Then in your UniCourse Class you could create a Constructor like this:

```
public UniCourse(int size) {
  this.students = new Student<T>(size);
}
```

And finally you can call your Constructor with this line:

```
UniCourse<Integer> uniCourse = new UniCourse<Integer>(20);
```

To access the data Array created in your Student class you can simply do something like this:

```
this.students.data;
```